# SSRS - Text Box Properties - Action - Go to Report - How to match to Table characteristics

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, ssms

I don't use SSRS that much so apologies if this is simple but i haven't found what i am looking for through googling.

I have a matrix table with Date down the left handside as =Format(CDATE(Fields!Involved_From_Date.Value), "yyyy-MMM") to group it by month and a simple "Country" straight from the dataset across the top.

When previewed i get a table like so:

```
 Involved Date | Australia | Singapore | South Africa
 --------------|-----------|-----------|--------------
    2018-Jan   |    0      |     3     |     9
    2018-Feb   |    0      |     1     |     5
    2018-Mar   |    1      |     4     |     1
```

I have set the Action to link to a data extract so when i click for e.g. the "9", the extract should load with all accounts for South Africa from Jan 2018. 
It loads South Africa correctly but it keeps giving me the entire date parameter of the parent report even though i haven't added the date parameters to the "Use these parameters to run the report".

So i don't want it to match the parameters at the top as this isn't necessarily whats in the table. I know how to pass parameters through but that's not what i want here. I need it to match the tables horizontal and vertical categories.

All data is from a T SQL query.

Comment: Or if i add the Date parameters it just goes for the first day everytime when i have specified it month. It seems to negate the format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to change the filter for the query in the Drill Through report to match the year/month format that you are passing.

```
WHERE Format(CDATE(Fields!Involved_From_Date.Value), "yyyy-MMM") = @START_DATE
```

In the initial report, set the Subreport parameter to pass the same year/month date format to that date parameter.

```
=Format(CDATE(Fields!Involved_From_Date.Value), "yyyy-MMM")
```

[image]